# How to implement connectivity code to my activity and fragment page?

Tags: android

I found this code here on stackoverflow..

```
package com.emil.android.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

/**
 * Check device's network connectivity and speed 
 * @author emil http://stackoverflow.com/users/220710/emil
 *
 */
public class Connectivity {

    /**
     * Get the network info
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity to a Wifi network
     * @param context
     * @param type
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity to a mobile network
     * @param context
     * @param type
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }

    /**
     * Check if there is fast connectivity
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
    }

    /**
     * Check if the connection is fast
     * @param type
     * @param subType
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
        if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return true;
        }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            switch(subType){
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                return false; // ~ 100 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
            /*
             * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
             * to appropriate level to use these
             */
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
                return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
                return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
                return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
                return false; // ~25 kbps 
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
                return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
            // Unknown
            case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I just want to know how can i implement this code to my code for indexactivity`.

Here is my `indexactivity`

```
package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class IndexActivity extends Activity {

    Button joinbutton, signbutton;
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        //boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
        if(isConnected){

        }else{
            nointernet();
        }


        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);

        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        joinbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.joinbutton);
        signbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signbutton);

        // Capture button clicks
        joinbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        signbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(authenticate() == true){
            /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);*/
            displayUserDetails();
        }
    }

    private boolean authenticate() {
        if (userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void displayUserDetails(){
        User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

        if(user.customers_id==""){
        }else{
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(IndexActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }

    public void nointernet(){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("There seems to be a problem with your connection.");
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Edit Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }

        });
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Reload", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Stop the activity
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
        AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.show();
        TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

In my indexactivity i use this code to check connection..

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
        activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
//boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
if(isConnected){

}else{
    nointernet();
}
```

How do I use the code above and display a message every time it returns false?

Comment: Create object of Connectivity class in your activity and Fragment where ever you want to use and call the public method relevant for your operation. Suppose You have a Connectivity conn=new Connectivity(); to get the network info call conn.getNetworkInfo(MainActivity.this);

Comment: can you complete the code in my indexactivity for sample? post an answer.. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace these lines in your onCreate

```
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        //boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
        if(isConnected){

        }else{
            nointernet();
        }
```

to

```
 Connectivity connectivity=new Connectivity();
  if(connectivity.isConnected(IndexActivity.this))
    {
    }else{
               nointernet();

    }
```

Comment: do i need to do this?  `Connectivity connectivity=new Connectivity();
 if(connectivity.isConnected(IndexActivity.this)) {

 }else{
  nointernet();
 }

 if(connectivity.isConnectedWifi(IndexActivity.this)) {

 }else{
  nointernet();
 }

 if(connectivity.isConnectedMobile(IndexActivity.this)) {

 }else{
  nointernet();
 }

 if(connectivity.isConnectedFast(IndexActivity.this)) {

 }else{
  nointernet();
 }`

Comment: you can club all if condition if you want to specify the generic funtcion to all . In this case you have nointernet() as a common method. Anyhow the isConnected method should give you connectivity of the devices irrespective of whether it is connected to wifi, mobiledata.

Comment: No issue. Everyone are new at initial stage and you will gain experience eventually . All the best :)